# A .NET API service shows (code=exited, status=203/EXEC) when Deploying to an Ubuntu Server

Tags: asp.net, .net, ubuntu, server

I want to deploy a WebAPI create with .NET 5 to a Hetzner server, I have deployed it based on the steps of this website [Deploy .NET](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-deploy-net-core-application-on-linux/).
Everything works fine, until I run the Service and check its status, it shows an error with my `WebApi.dll`

```
root@ubuntu:/# systemctl status  MinAPIservice.service
● MinAPIservice.service - ASP .NET Web Application
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/MinAPIservice.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2023-06-13 09:58:40 UTC; 1s ago
    Process: 52726 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /var/www/MinAPI/MinWebApi.dll (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
   Main PID: 52726 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
        CPU: 775us
```

And to find the problem I have run the following command
`/etc/systemd/system# /usr/bin/dotnet /var/www/MinAPI/WebApi.dll` in the system directory, and shows the following error:

```
root@ubuntu:/etc/systemd/system# /usr/bin/dotnet /var/www/MinAPI/WebApi.dll
You must install or update .NET to run this application.

App: /var/www/MinAPI/WebApi.dll
Architecture: x64
Framework: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '5.0.0' (x64)
.NET location: /usr/lib/dotnet/

The following frameworks were found:
   6.0.16 at [/root/.dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  7.0.5 at [/root/.dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]

Learn about framework resolution:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/app-launch-failed

To install missing framework, download:
https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.AspNetCore.App&framework_version=5.0.0&arch=x64&rid=ubuntu.23.04-x64
```

Now my Server shows 503 - Service Unavailable ...

I have tried to Install .NET 5.0 , but it's no longer supported for Ubuntu 23.04, also tried to install .NET 6.0 still the same, I want to find a solution to this error to run my API using Swagger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error says you don't have .NET 5 framework installed, but you have higher versions so you can run it on a higher version, but you must [configure roll-forward behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/runtime-discovery/troubleshoot-app-launch?pivots=os-windows#configure-roll-forward-behavior) for the application.

Note that since using this option lets the application run on a different framework version than the one for which it was designed, it may result in unintended behavior due to changes between versions of a framework.

Or you could upgrade the framework version of your API to the latest .NET 7.

Comment: Yes, I have decided to Upgrade the .NET to 7, do you have a source to help me with that?

Comment: @BasharAl-shaibani There were almost no breaking changes between 5 and 7, so this  should be pretty simple: Download the .Net 7 SDK on your development machine, open the project in Visual Studio and change the framework in the project settings. Or, if you didn't use Visual Studio, edit the .csproj file manually. Then rebuild the DLL.

Comment: @BasharAl-shaibani I would also look to move to .Net 8, which is an LTS (long term support) release. That means installing .Net at both locations (development and production server), but it means you'll have security support through near the end of 2026 without needing to make additional changes.